# How to see that $St(\omega, \mathcal U)=\Psi(\mathcal E)$ for any open cover $\mathcal U$?

Tags: general-topology

[image]

How to see that $St(\omega, \mathcal U)=\Psi(\mathcal E)$ for any open cover $\mathcal U$?

Thanks ahead.